# Example of Chrome and Firefox Extensions sharing the same code?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, cross-browser, automation, firefox-addon

I am looking for a sample project that would compile a chrome and firefox extension that would run some JavaScript code after a page is loaded.

I already wrote a Chrome extension that does this, but I am looking for something cross-browser, that would allow me to build the same extension for Chrome and Firefox.

If this would also allow me to publish the extensions it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You may refer this link http://www.extensionfactory.com/labs/conversion/ 
Here you can get firefox extension by submitting chrome extension.

Comment: The link is dead :(

Answer (score 0):

With the [Crossrider's](http://crossrider.com) framework you can build a cross-browser extension using only one code base that will work on Chrome, Firefox and also Internet Explorer and Safari.

So, with only using javascript single code base and the Crossrider API you can easily build your first cross-browser extension in no time.

(Disclosure: I work at Crossrider)

Comment: The link is dead :(